# How to detect when other applications are playing and stop my media player

Tags: android, kotlin, android-audiomanager

I have tried to do this using AudioManager but when I do the following it doesn't work. If I play my mediaplayer and open a youtube video, the music stops correctly in my mediaplayer. But if now I pause the YouTube video, I put my mediaplayer back on and put the YouTube video back on, the goodbye overlaps and it doesn't detect again that it has lost focus.

Ese es el metodo que he creado en mi servicio y lo llamo en el onCreate():

```
private fun focusCall(){

    val mOnAudioFocusChangeListener: OnAudioFocusChangeListener

    mOnAudioFocusChangeListener = OnAudioFocusChangeListener { focusChange ->

        when (focusChange) {

            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN -> {
                if(isPlaying){
                    playMusic()
                }
            }

            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT -> {
                if(isPlaying){
                    playMusic()
                }
            }

            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK -> {
                if(isPlaying){
                    playMusic()
                }
            }

            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS -> {
                if(isPlaying){
                    pauseMusic()
                }
            }

            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT -> {
                if(isPlaying){
                    pauseMusic()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var audioManager : AudioManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager

    var result = am.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)

}
```

Is there an easier way to perform audio focus recognition? A library or something similar?

Comment: Could you explain. For eg if you want the music to pause when some other application is running putting it in onPause should be enough. But that's not what you want right?

Comment: When another application is playing, pause my media player.